# std::vector and winapi windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to manage my new windows in one vector, but I've got problems with it.
To create a working window class I have to put

```
while( GetMessage( & Komunikat, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
{
    TranslateMessage( & Komunikat );
    DispatchMessage( & Komunikat );
}
```

because of this loop windows are added to the vector after destroying them. How to deal with that?

---

After deleting that loop, i have problems with handling messages i child window. When i try to write something in Edit box program crashes (i think it's something with editing them because sending text to it also creshes program)

Comment: Would you clarify a bit more?  I'm not sure what your problem is, nor do I see a vector in your code.

Comment: Sorry, but we're going to need a LOT more context than this. Provide from Komunikat source, etc, please.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MzSEvmr0

Here's my code, it's little bit messy but i'll try to point my problems

1. Komunikat is a MSG struct from winapi
2. i'm adding to vector  new windows at line 310 

Everything works but function void MainWindow::isOpen() doesn't (beacause of that non adding to vector class ChatWindow) and by non adding i mean that it won't be in vector untill window isn't destroyed

Comment: Your problem is possibly line 317 where you've omitted the LOWORD(wParam), and so when you click the button nothing will happen. Also, you should really have 1 switch statement not 2.

Comment: at this moment i don't even use this button(but it does work), so even when i delete it or do it right it won't change anything. Thanks for advice remake it to one switch

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're running a message loop within a message loop. The ChatWindow constructor creates the window and then runs a message loop and doesn't return until the window is destroyed.

You don't need to do this. Your program only needs one message loop (the one in MainWindow), and it will retrieve and dispatch messages for all currently open windows on the thread.

(For reference, the sample code was posted at http://pastebin.com/MzSEvmr0).

Comment: THANK YOU, I really don't know why i put it there, and as long as evrything was working i didn't care. So thank you again

Comment: After deleting that loop, i have problems with handling messages i child window. When i try to write something in Edit box program crashes (i think it's something with editing them because sending text to it also creshes program)